# Element-wise reciprocal notation

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, notation

Does there exist notation for the following operator?
$$[\frac{1}{a_{1}},\frac{1}{a_{2}},...,\frac{1}{a_{n}}]^{T} = \text{invert}( [a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}]^{T})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In suffix notation, used in vector calculus, a vector $$(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) $$may be represented simply by
$$a_i$$ where the index is understood to take all values allowed ($1$ to $n$ in this case). This is neat and compact and quite powerful.

You could then use this to write the vector whose components are reciprocals of your original vector as $$1/a_i$$